# JS: replace text char by char, which can contain html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have text with many tags and formatting like this:

```
<u>
  1
  <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
    <span style="font-size: 45px;">2</span>
    <span class="Raleway">34</span>
  </span>
  <i>
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);" class="Raleway">5</span>
    6
  </i>
</u>
```

The task is to replace text using JS or jQuery, but keep all formatting and tags. For example, replace current "123456" with "abcdef". Number of chars is always the same. The result should be:

```
<u>
  a
  <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
    <span style="font-size: 45px;">b</span>
    <span class="Raleway">cd</span>
  </span>
  <i>
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);" class="Raleway">e</span>
    f
  </i>
</u>
```

I have no good idea, how to solve this, so I'll be glad to receive any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with any string:

```js
function isTextNode (node) {
  return node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
}

function walkTextNodes (node, fn) {
  var children = node.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = children.item(i);
    if (isTextNode(child)) {
      fn(child);
    } else {
      walkTextNodes(child, fn);
    }
  }
}

function replaceContents (string) {
  var index = 0;          // the current index in the string
  
  walkTextNodes(container, function (node) {
    var text = node.nodeValue.trim();
    var length = text.length;
    node.nodeValue = string.slice(index, index + length);
    index += length;
  });
}

var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var string = input.value; // the new string
  replaceContents(string);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <u>
    1
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
      <span style="font-size: 45px;">2</span>
      <span class="Raleway">34</span>
    </span>
    <i>
      <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);" class="Raleway">5</span>
      6
    </i>
  </u>
  
</div>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter the new string">
<button>Replace</button>
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you very much. But I have question: why it ignores spaces? I replaced this  `var text = node.nodeValue.trim();` on this  `var text = node.nodeValue;` but it still ignores spaces. For example, _222 33_ became _123_ (with `trim()`) or _123 33_ (without `trim()`), part after space char is lost (`trim()`) or is not touched (no `trim()`).

Comment: My fault. Without `trim()` everything is fine. Thanks again. :)

Comment: You need `trim` to get rid of the whitespace in the markup (every new line and tab creates whitespace), which you normally want to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
 var fullHtml = $("u").html(); //This returns a string
 fullHtml = fullHtml.replace("1","a");
 fullHtml = fullHtml.replace("2","b");
 fullHtml = fullHtml.replace("3","c");
 fullHtml = fullHtml.replace("4","d");

 $("u").html(fullHtml);
```

You could also improve by using a for loop:

```
 var alphabet = ["", "a","b","c","d","e"];
 var fullHtml = $("u").html(); //This returns a string
 for(var i=1; i<6; i++){
      fullHtml = fullHtml.replace(""+i,alphabet[i]);
 }
 $("u").html(fullHtml);
```

Comment: There could be not only 123456, but 000000, aaaaaa etc. It means, symbols are not unique and cannot be replaced in this way.

Answer (score 0):

There you have a solution.

I hope it works good for you!

```js
var originals = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'];
var replacers = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
var html_content = $("u").html();

for(const [index, item] of originals.entries()) {
  var regEx = new RegExp("(" + item + ")(?!([^<]+)?>)", "gi");
  
  html_content = html_content.replace(regEx, replacers[index]);
} 

$("u").html(html_content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<u>
  1
  <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
    <span style="font-size: 45px;">2</span>
    <span class="Raleway">34</span>
  </span>
  <i>
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);" class="Raleway">5</span>
    6
  </i>
</u>
```

Comment: The problem is that there could be not only 123456, but 000000, aaaaaa etc. It means, symbols are not unique.

Comment: I don't think there is a dynamic solution to do that... at least nothing come to my mind right know :/